# Clarification about the question of whether neutrinos are their own antineutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter, neutrinos, majorana-fermions, leptons

There are various pages that say we can distinguish between neutrinos and antineutrinos.

- [Why do we not know whether or not neutrinos are their own antiparticles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/403037)
- [Why are neutrino and antineutrino cross sections different?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191167)

However, other (not too old) sources claim that we still don't know whether neutrinos and antineutrinos are the same particle (as of 2022).

- [Neutrinos from beta decay](https://neutrinos.fnal.gov/sources/beta-decay/)
- [Is the neutrino its own antiparticle?](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/is-the-neutrino-its-own-antiparticle)

If we can distinguish between neutrinos and antineutrinos, then how is it still possible that neutrinos and antineutrinos might be the same?

Comment: I think you second link explains the theoretical possibility, that  from the existing data it could be so.

Comment: You are probably faked out by simplistic science journalism gobbledygook hype. An ***ever so small***  Majorana mass term violates lepton number by a bit and transitions $\nu_L$ to $\overline {\nu_R}$ in neutrinoless double β  decay, but this does *not* mean these two states are indistinguishable, as you seem to imagine! They have dramatically different couplings and experimental signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up until now, every experimental result involving neutrinos can be explained simply by helicity - left-handed neutrinos couple to leptons and right-handed neutrinos couple to anti-leptons. These right-handed neutrinos are currently referred to as antineutrinos, but we don't actually have any evidence that neutrinos/antineutrinos have a definite lepton number that is conserved in their interactions independently of helicity.  If not, the only thing distinguishing neutrinos from "anti-"neutrinos is their helicity, which isn't used to differentiate particles from antiparticles, so the neutrino would be its own anti-particle. This is somewhat analogous to photons, which are also their own anti-particle but which have two helicity (circular polarization) states.

Here are a couple of the [many questions on Majorana neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=majorana+neutrinos) whose answers may also help:

- [Majorana neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580424/majorana-neutrinos)
- [If a neutrino and his antineutrino has different helicity how can it be a possibility that it is a Majorana particle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240788/if-a-neutrino-and-his-antineutrino-has-different-helicity-how-can-it-be-a-possib)

One process that could happen if neutrinos have a Majorana nature is [neutrinoless double beta decays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrinoless_double_beta_decay#Overview), but this has not yet been observed.